# Обновить метод работы с ссылками

Tags: java, android

Накатал **рабочий** метод(для видео в youtube) в котором обрабатываю ссылку пользователя(вытаскиваю ID и подставляю в *шаблонную* форму ссылки) :

```
private String onUserInput(String input) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
    String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(videoID)) {
        String[] str = input.split("/");
        videoID = str[str.length - 1];
    }
    url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/0.jpg";
    Log.d("url", url + " " + controlList.get(23).getImageUploads().size());
    adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return url;
}
```

Помогите правильно "обновить" метод и для ссылки в vimeo:

```
https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/183364240.json
```

Как я понял, необходимо еще парсить данные с ссылки, так как .json
И уже после того как вытащу ссылку можно будет обращаться к любым размерам картинки(thumbnail_small, thumbnail_medium, thumbnail_large), как примерно здесь:

```
https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/595198868_100x75.jpg
```

Пытался обновить метод следующим образом, но еще до того как прочёл про JSON:

```
private void useLinkInput(String input, EVideo video) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
    String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(videoID)) {
        String[] str = input.split("/");
        videoID = str[str.length - 1];
    }
    if (video == EVideo.YOUTUBE) {
        source = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/";
    } else {
        source = "http://VIMEO.CN";
    }
    url = source + videoID + "/0.jpg";
    Log.d("url", url);

}
```

Переменные объявил т.о:

```
public enum EVideo {
    YOUTUBE,
    VIMEO
}
```

Не уверен что попытка "*засчитана*" так как с самой json операцией возникают проблемы, как возможно её запихнуть к нам в код?

Comment: Вам нужно из строки `https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/183364240.json` получить число `183364240`?

Comment: @post_zeew ну типо того. и потом это число(ID) добавить к моему url, но уже к https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/ , дополнительно к тому методу, что в вопросе, т.е. думаю второй if просто дописать или что то в этом духе.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, примеры входных и выходных данных в обоих случаях.

Comment: @post_zeew для метода описанного в вопросе используется любой тип ссылки с youtube.

Comment: Это не ответ. Впрочем, как хотите.

Comment: @post_zeew эм, что вы имеете в виду? вам конкретно ссылку дать или что?) не уверен что Вы поняли функцию метода. Ну или поясните более конкретней, что Вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Да, конкретные ссылки. Например, на входе имеем `https://...`, на выходе – `https://...`. И так для всех *разновидностей* входных данных.

Comment: @post_zeew на вход https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehMGQqeV7qM&feature=youtu.be на выход D/url: http://img.youtube.com/vi/ehMGQqeV7qM/0.jpg 1

Comment: А остальные? Вы все эти комбинации лучше включите в Ваш вопрос, чтобы читать удобнее было.

Comment: а как выглядит ссылка на изображение в vimeo?

Comment: @post_zeew для ютуба я и включил, как для обычной ссылки так и на случай шортлинка.

Comment: @metalurgus https://vimeo.com/183171690 , ну и та ссылка которую я добавил в вопросе(для преобразования) если правильно нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `String getLink(String oldLink)` преобразует:

1. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehMGQqeV7qM&feature=youtu.be` в `http://img.youtube.com/vi/ehMGQqeV7qM/0.jpg`;
2. `https://vimeo.com/183171690` в `https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/183171690.json`.

Собственно, код:

```
private String getLink(String oldLink) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(oldLink);
    String host = uri.getHost().startsWith("www.") ? uri.getHost().substring(4) : uri.getHost();

    switch (host) {
        case "youtube.com": 
            return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + uri.getQueryParameter("v") + "/0.jpg";
        case "vimeo.com" : 
            return "https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video" + uri.getPath() + ".json";
        default: 
            return oldLink;
    }
}
```

А обработку некорректных исходных данных – сами.

Comment: К сожалению такой вариант не подходит, дело в том что ссылка с vimeo содержит .json. Как я понял, нужно сначала парсить файл, а потом только добавлять, поправьте меня если не прав.